# Get HLF blockchain info

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

here's my problem.

I have set a development env for HLF using Vagrant, made some changes to HLF source and built new docker images.
Then I deployed a network with 3 peers and 1 orderer, starting from custom HLF images and installed the basic chaincode that uses 'a' and 'b' variable as assets, making some operation (chaincode_example02).

Now I would like to see blockchain info such as blocks hash, ledger height and so on. How can access this info? Is there a way without using any app made with SDKs? For instance, some command executed by CLI.

If not, what's the fastest way to get this info? Thanks.

Comment: You can take a look at Query System ChainCode in the documentation, and the relevant code, that should give you the idea how to do these in CLI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved the problem.

This does what i needed:

```
docker exec -it cli bash peer channel getinfo -c <channel-name>
```